# How do i define 'HTTPCookieProcessor' global name?

Tags: python, cookies

I have this code:

```
 class API(object):

        def __init__(self):
            self.baseuri = "http://api.xxx.xxx"
            self.cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
            self.cp = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj)
            self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(self.cp)
```

the error is: `NameError: global name 'HTTPCookieProcessor' is not defined`  How come?
 P.S.:

```
 >>> a = api.API()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Python27\lib\lib\xxxxx\api.py", line 9, in __init__
        self.cp = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj)
    NameError: global name 'HTTPCookieProcessor' is not defined
```

Comment: The code posted is not giving you that error. Can you correct the posted code & include a full traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is probably contained in the three or so lines that got cut from the top of your api.py file when you pasted the code in your question.  If I had to guess, I'd say they looked something like:

```
import cookielib
import urllib2
# <blank line>
```

Though I wouldn't be surprised if the `import urllib2` line was actually something different, which is causing the issue somehow.  If that's the case, try replacing whatever you have with just `import urllib2`; otherwise can you post the full file?

Comment: i fixed it!! :) The mistake was: i had a folder called lib inside of  PythonDir/Lib folder, so i had PythonDir/Lib/lib. So, i fixed by renaming it to PythonDir/Lib/mylib  :)

Comment: Oh, I missed the significance of C:\Python27\lib\lib\xxxxx\api.py; typically you don't want to have your user-level code inside of the C:\Python27\ directory.  Put it somewhere in My Documents or whatever, and then use the %PYTHONPATH% environment variable to tell python that it should look in My Documents\mylib in addition to the standard lib.  See: http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables

Comment: What do you mean by user-level code?? Application code?? I placed it inside of PythonDir/Lib because it's Library code (not application)

Comment: I meant anything that's not part of the python standard library.  There's a `site-packages` directory for packages that get installed via `easy_install` or `pip`; typically those are .egg files from PyPI.  Everything that you'd write would go in eg. My Documents\mylib, which gets listed in %PYTHONPATH% so that other scripts you write can access it.